# Should one interleave tests?

Tags: unit-testing

While I am not entirely new to testing and unit-testing in particular I often hesitate in regards to stuff like the following:

Imagine the following implementation I want to test (yes, I know TDD ftw ;))

```
private Value0Service value0Service = new Value0Service();
private Value1Service value1Service = new Value1Service();

public SomeInfo readInfo(final Long id, final Value value0, final Value value1) {
    final Value1 actualValue0 = fetchValue0IfNullElseReturnGiven(id, value0);
    final Value2 actualValue1 = fetchValue1IfNullElseReturnGiven(value1);

    return SomeInfo(actualValue0, actualValue1);
}

private Value fetchValue0IfNullElseReturnGiven(Long id, Value value0) {
    if(value0== null) {
        return value0Service.getById(id);
    }
    return value0;
}

private Value fetchValue1IfNullElseReturnGiven(Value value0, Value value1) {
    if(value1 == null) {
        return value1Service.getByValue0(value0);
    }
    return value1;
}
```

While this is a constructed example I hope the intent is clear.

Now if I write tests is it enough to cover the behaviour for each "fetch"-method, or should I also cross my tests?
What I mean by that:

Do I only assert that my return value of `readInfo` `SomeInfo` has the respective parameter set or do I always check for both?

(I am sorry, it's difficult to explain in English) should I interleave my tests like:

```
// ValueServices are to be treated as mocks from here, so imagine Value0Service value0ServiceMock = mock(Value0Service.class) in the tests!

@Test
public void ifBothValuesAreGivenThenSomeInfoIsFilledWithGivenForBoth() {
    Value value0 = new Value();
    Value value1 = new Value();

    SomeInfo info = myTestObject.readInfo(VALID_ID, value0, value1);
    assertThat(info.getValue0()).isEqualTo(value0);
    assertThat(info.getValue1()).isEqualTo(value1);
}

@Test
public void ifValue0IsNullAndValue1IsNotThenSomeInfoIsFilledWithFetchedForValue0AndGivenForValue1() {
    Value value1 = new Value();

    Value fetchedValue0 = new Value();
    doReturn(fetchedValue0).when(value0ServiceMock).getById(VALID_ID);

    SomeInfo info = myTestObject.readInfo(VALID_ID, null, value1); 
    assertThat(info.getValue0()).isEqualTo(fetchedValue0);
    assertThat(info.getValue1()).isEqualTo(value1);
}

@Test
public void ifValue0IsNotNullAndValue1IsThenSomeInfoIsFilledWithGivenForValue0AndFetchedForValue1() {
    Value value0 = new Value();

    Value fetchedValue1 = new Value();
    doReturn(fetchedValue1).when(value1ServiceMock).getByValue(value0);

    SomeInfo info = myTestObject.readInfo(VALID_ID, value0, null);
    assertThat(info.getValue0()).isEqualTo(value0);
    assertThat(info.getValue1()).isEqualTo(fetchedValue1);
}

@Test
public void ifValue0IsNullAndValue1IsNullThenSomeInfoIsFilledWithFetchedForBoth() {
    Value fetchedValue0 = new Value();
    Value fetchedValue1 = new Value();
    doReturn(fetchedValue0).when(value0ServiceMock).getById(VALID_ID);
    doReturn(fetchedValue1).when(value1ServiceMock).getByValue(fetchedValue0);

    SomeInfo info = myTestObject.readInfo(VALID_ID, null, null);

    assertThat(info.getValue0()).isEqualTo(fetchedValue0);
    assertThat(info.getValue1()).isEqualTo(fetchedValue1);
}
```

Should I always add asserts for both values, or only for one? In both cases I would write 4 tests, so I wonder, because I was told that a good way to handle assertions is to just have one per test, else you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular example, you should implement the equals method for `SomeInfo`. This will allow you to have only one assertion:

```
SomeInfo expectedInfo = new SomeInfo(...);

assertThat(myTestObject.readInfo(VALID_ID, null, null)).isEqualTo(expectedInfo);
```

However, your question still stands and is something I come up against all the time. Having only one assertion per test is essential for making sure tests are readable by a future programmer. The trick is to decide what counts as "one assertion". Let's look at your example:

```
assertThat(info.getValue0()).isEqualTo(fetchedValue0);
assertThat(info.getValue1()).isEqualTo(fetchedValue1);
```

You could argue that although there are two calls to the `assertThat` method, this is really just one logical assertion - we are checking the value of `info` is correct. The problems happen when you have two assertions like this:

```
@Test
public void multipleAssertions() {
    Value value1 = serviceUnderTest.getValue(...);
    assertThat(value1).isEqualTo(expectedValue1);

    Value value2 = serviceUnderTest.getValue(...);
    assertThat(value2).isEqualTo(expectedValue2);
}
```

This kind of code makes the tests confusing and difficult to maintain. You will often find that such tests are not named very well too.

One final point: you only get this problem when you are writing tests *after* the code has already been written. As you say, "TDD ftw!". If the tests are written first, following by the smallest possible amount of code to make the test pass, you never have this problem because you simply stop writing the test after the first assertion and move on to the next test.